# TSQL Selection Criteria For Join - Left Join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

```
Select  *
From    cacheAttendanceMeasures cam 
        Left Join dmcUserSelectedAttendanceMeasures usam on usam.attMeasureID = cam.attMeasureID
          And usam.personID = @personID
          And usam.pageID = @pageID
```

I understand that the above query will return all rows from cacheAttendanceMeasures as well as any rows from dmcUserSelectedAttendanceMeasures and dmcUserSelectedStudentMonths where the conditions match. What I would really like it to do is this:

1. If the left join(s) don't match, then return all rows from cacheAttendanceMeasures -- so what it is currently doing
2. However, if the left join(s) DO match, then return ONLY the rows that match from cacheAttendanceMeasures

Is this possible?

**EDIT:**
I simplified the query above to only include one Left Join table, I don't want to over-complicate the issue.

Below are dataset examples I'd like to see returned based on if there are no matches between the tables versus there is a match:

**cam Table**
cID   attMeasureID   Value
1             1                   530
2             2                   95.7
3             3                   380
4             4                  742.57
5             5                   200

**usam Table**
uID  personID  pageID  attMeasureID
1       877450       31           1
2       923450       28           2
3       877450       31           3
4       369842       28           4
5       212193       25           1

**Dataset to Return if @personID = 577597 & @pageID = 20:**
CID  attMeasureID  Value  uID  pageID  attMeasureID
1                  1            530   null     nul            null
2                  2            95.7  null     null           null
3                  3            380   null     null           null
4                  4         742.57 null     null           null
5                  5           200    null     null           null

**Dataset to Return if @personID = 877450 & @pageID = 31:**
CID  attMeasureID  Value  uID  personID  pageID  attMeasureID
1             1                530      1      877450      31           1
3             3                380      3      877450      31           3

Comment: Maybe you mean this: `where dmcUserSelectedAttendanceMeasures  is not null` for example  as I don't know if you want both left join tables to be null, I just used this example for one...   but it seems like 1 and 2 are mutually exclusive.  Provide some sample expected output from all three tables to help clairify what you're after.  assume T1, T2,T3 table names: if records in T1 and T2 but not T3... show what?  if records in T1 and T3 show what? if records in T1, T2,T3 show what and if only in T1 shhow what?  Perhaps you just need to join ussm on personID and pageID and limit in the first left

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I am getting ready to leave work but will provide more specifics tomorrow...but hopefully this will help: This query will feed data to an html report. The two tables being joined store filters that the user has specified.  For instance there are six attendance measures: Attendance Rate, Total Days Enrolled, Total Days Missed, etc.  If the user only wants to see Attendance Rate, they can select that & that's all I want to return.  If they haven't selected a filter, then I want to return everything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what  results you want...

At first I thought maybe something like this..

```
SELECT  *
FROM cacheAttendanceMeasures cam 
LEFT JOIN dmcUserSelectedAttendanceMeasures usam 
   on usam.attMeasureID = cam.attMeasureID
  And usam.personID = @personID
  And usam.pageID = @pageID
LEFT JOIN dmcUserSelectedStudentMonths ussm 
   on ussm.monthSeq = cam.pupilMonth
  And ussm.personID = USAM.PersonID
  And ussm.pageID = USAM.PageId
```

--This where clause would seem silly as it negates the left joins; making them inner joins  and violates #1 as to what you're after.  so I don't think that's what you're after...

```
WHERE ussm.personID is not null
and usam.personID is not null
```

So with rule 2 are you saying... if a single record isn't null, then only return records which exist in both Left joined tables and the 1st table?

So given:

```
T1  T2   T3
X   X    X
Y   NULL Y
Z   Y    NULL
T   NULL NULL
```

I think you would want just record X
But Given
So given:

```
T1  T2   T3
X   X    NULL
Y   NULL Y
Z   Y    NULL
T   NULL NULL
```

I think you would want X, Y Z, and T...  need better clairification.